# Rescale Vector R

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a vector of integers such as:

```
> x
[1]  1  1  1  4  4 13 13 14
```

I am looking for an efficient way in R to rescale the vector to integers 1 to the max of the unique number of elements.  Therefore the resulting vector would be:

```
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
```

Seems like a simple problem but I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to do it.  In practice this vector is large (around 500).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `match(x, sort(unique(x)))`:

```
x <- sample(1:50, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
benchmark(as.integer(factor(x)), match(x, sort(unique(x))),
          replications = 20, columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))
#                        test elapsed relative
# 1     as.integer(factor(x))   18.44    10.36
# 2 match(x, sort(unique(x)))    1.78     1.00

identical(as.integer(factor(x)), match(x, sort(unique(x))))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following command, assuming that `v` is your vector

```
rank( v )
```

see `?rank` for more information.

Well, this does give another result, but is correct as ranking, which is what I thought you want to achieve. To get your preferred result, do

```
as.integer( factor( v ) )
```

Comment: Actually this returns different result than `1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4`